# Comandos CMD/Shell são fora do escopo?

Tags: debate

Acabei de responder uma sobre formatar comando CMD (prompt windows).
[Comando start com caracteres especiais (CMD)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215408)

Tecnicamente é fora do escopo, mas respondi assim mesmo.

Esse caso específico, do link, pode ser tolerado?

A minha inclinação é fechar pois se permite um "tem que permitir outro", confundindo os usuários do site que ficam sem saber como interpretar o que é fora do escopo.